# How to call javascript function inside another function onsubmit form?

Tags: javascript, html

```
function toggle1() {
    //code toogle1

    function toggle2() {
        //code toogle2
    }
}
```

I want to call `toggle2()` in the onsubmit of the form:

```
<form name="myForm" action="blabla.php" onsubmit="return toogle2()" method="post">
```

I have no clue about this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want this? Why not just call `toggle1()`?

Comment: @Anickyan because there are some things that make i want call toogle2() inside toogle1() , is there a way to call toogle2 ? thanks

Comment: you need to return toggle2 in toggle1 to access it out of the toggle1 scope

Comment: Just take `toggle2()` outside of `toggle1()` to make it global. Case solved.

Comment: @user2449684 If you want to call toggle2 from inside toggle1 you could just move it outside, it would still be callable by toggle1. The only reason I see for doing this would be to hide toggle2 from any code outside toggle1.

Comment: @user2449684 Maybe you could post some more code so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can declare function toggle2 at the same level as toggle1 in this case at global scope and then use as callback function (or call in toggle1 if you want it), but if you use this function as closer to access data in toggle1 you can call immediately toggle1 function and assign on an variable and return reference on toggle2 function body

Comment: thanks all , case solved , i will move toogle2() outside toogle1() and change my code

Answer (score 1):

`toggle2` is defined within the scope of `toggle1`, so it isn't a global and is not accessible.

You could assign it to a global:

```
function toggle1() {
    //code toogle1

    function toggle2() {
        //code toogle2
    }

    window.toggle2 = toggle2;

}
```

… but it wouldn't be available until `toggle1` was called.

Globals are generally a bad idea though. In most cases you are usually better off not using them. This makes the `onXXX` attributes unusable so you would have to switch to something more modern ([`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener), either directly or through an abstraction library).

```
function toggle1() {
    //code toogle1

    function toggle2() {
        //code toogle2
    }

    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', toggle2);

}
```

You'd still need to call `toggle1` before it could be used though.

Comment: thanks @Quentin for the answer , it worked , but you right still need to call toggle1 first , really bad method what i do , i will move toogle2() to outside

Answer (score 1):

```
function toggle1() {
    //code toogle1
    toggle2();
}

function toggle2() {
   //code toogle2
}
```

If I was you,I would like use the above way